# Ceil function in finding median

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ using "Programming Principles and Practice using C++" by Bjarne Stroustroup. In the following question of finding median, I have problem with the `ceil` function. Say, for example, I input 14 entries then value of `a` should be 6 and value of `b` should be 7. But the value of `b` is coming out 6.

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

using namespace std;

int main() 
{ vector<double> temps;
  for(double temp;cin>>temp;)
     {temps.push_back(temp);
     }
  sort(temps);
  for(double temp : temps)
     cout << temp << " " ;
  int size = temps.size();

  if(size%2 == 0)
    { int a,b,c;
      a = temps[floor((size + 1)/2) - 1]; cout << a;
      **b = temps[ceil((size + 1)/2) - 1 ]; cout << b;**
      cout<<"Median temperature:"<<(a+b)/2<<'\n';
    }
  else
    cout<<"Median temperature:"<<temps[((size + 1)/2) - 1]<<'\n';
return 0;
}
```

[std_lib_facilties.h link](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/std_lib_facilities.h)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since `size` is an `int`, `(size+1)/2` will perform an integer division, and will return only the whole part of the division. Applying `ceil` to it, as you saw, is pointless.

You could work around it by defining `size` as a `double`, or casting it inline:

```
**b = temps[ceil((((double)size) + 1)/2) - 1 ];
```